# What is are the distinct names for these verbs: 'Display' and 'Displays'

Tags: verbs, past-tense, present-tense, present-participles

Given the statement `Click this button to display your presentation` and `Clicking this button displays your presentation`.

I assume both the words `display` and `displays` are verbs but what is the name of one verb and what is the name of the other? `Display` sounds like a commanding verb. Displays sounds like an descriptive verb. Those are not the actual names but I am interested in the official naming difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence is [You] (implied subject) click (main verb) this button (direct object) to display your presentation ([an infinitive verb with a direct object; an infinitive phrase](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/infinitive_form.htm), used an adjective).

The second one is
Clicking this button (subject consisting of a gerund and its direct object) displays ([main verb](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/main-verb/)) your presentation. (direct object)